Is there a standard screwsize / thread for wiring applications?
A sewage grinder pump controller's screws are rusty.   I would like to replace them.

Is there a standard size screw or is it a free-for-all?

The rusty screws are probably the least of the problems.  Rust tends to spread, so rusty screw, rusty screw hole, rusty connection plate.  Want to bet the inside connections are not perfect either.

Those bottom screws are never coming out.

If you end up touching this, you'd do well to ask yourself how you could prevent such problems in the future. (Better enclosure, maybe?)


A sewage grinder pump controller's screws are rusty. I would like to replace them.

Don't.
First of all, touching corroded terminals leads to problems. Ideally, terminals should make a connection so tight that oxygen can't access the terminal interface - thus no corrosion of the actual electric interface.
Second, when there's corrosion, it's not just the screws. It's everything.
Either leave it alone, or replace the contactors and other components.

The terminations will differ between manufacturers and so will the screw size and threads. You have the manufacturer, you should have checked with them.
